# Raptor- Validation

Tags: validation, raptor

I need to make a raptor flowchart, which allows to get numbers and stop if I enter a letter or a character different to a number.

But I don't know how to make it in a flowchart

Idk which version of Raptor I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Use the loop, put your request for the user input inside it, and have the breaking condition be "`Is_Number(variable)`" where the variable is whatever you have defined the user's input to be. If it comes to yes, the input is a number, the program continues. If it is no, the loop keeps asking. Make sure to tell the user to only use numbers.

Additionally, if you need the number to be some values, you can also put those into the break condition, as long as you use the "and" operator, such as "`Is_Number(variable)` and `variable >=0`", in which case the program only continues if both the input is a number and if that number is greater than or equal to zero.

I hope that helps.